# Is NADPH sensitive and unstable in UV light?

Tags: biochemistry, stability

According to the MSDS for NADPH Tetrasodium Salt, it says to store it in a place away from heat and light. Does this include UV light or just visible light? I was told that a pure NADPH stock solution (with pH 7 phosphate buffer as solvent) could be re-used after absorbing UV light at 340 nm, but based on the MSDS it seems that shouldn't be the case. So my question is: could I reuse a sample of pure NADPH stock solution that was exposed to UV for my enzyme activity assay?

datasheets.scbt.com/sc-202725.pdf

https://www.interprise.com.br/produtos/download/90289.pdf

Answer (score 1):

NADPH isn't destroyed by absorbing 340 nm light; if it were, then spectrophotometry wouldn't be a good technique to monitor its concentration.  The primary stability concern with NADPH and NADH is acid-catalyzed decomposition.  A great 1986 article summarizing this phenomenon is available [here](http://www.clinchem.org/content/32/2/314.full.pdf).

Some highlights from the article:

- At 30 °C, the pseudo-first order rate constant for NADPH degradation in aqueous solution goes from 0.5 min$^{-1}$ at pH ~3 to $10^{-5}$ min$^{-1}$ at pH 10.  At pH 7 the rate constant is $10^{-3}$ min$^{-1}$.
- The rate is elevated slightly by higher concentrations of phosphate buffer, about 10x higher for 1 molar (!) phosphate vs. extrapolation to infinite-dilution  phosphate.

A secondary pathway for NAD(P)H decomposition is oxidation by atmospheric air, but it is usually pretty minor compared to acid degradation.

So I don't think there will be a big problem with light destroying your NADPH.  You might be able to re-use it, but it depends how long you let it sit in solution, and at what temperature.